# RSA Algorithm 1 Mod Phi = 1?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, modulo

On this [website](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-rsa-algorithm) it states for the calculation of "d" you must use the formula e.d = 1 Mod Phi. 
 I don't quite understand as I believed 1 Mod anything will result in 1 (or 0 in case 1 Mod 1). 
 This simplifies the formula to e.d = 1 which clearly is not correct with the given test values :
e = 17 , Phi = 3120 , d = 2753.

I would appreciate some clarification on how the RSA calculates the decryption key.

Comment: e\*d = 17 \* 2753 = 46801 = 1 + 15 \* 3120 = 1 + 15 \* phi = 1 mod phi.

Comment: Note for RSA it is _sufficient_ to have e·d congruent 1 mod phi(n) using Euler's totient (p-1)·(q-1) but not necessary; the necessary condition is mod lambda(n) using Carmichael's totient lcm(p-1,q-1). See wikipedia, which has this correct, unlike a site which prides itself on being incomplete. But this is not a programming or development issue, and there are already tens if not hundreds of Qs about it on crypto.stackexchange.com where it is ontopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia says this is a [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). The formula should be read as *e* * *d* equals 1, when the result is expressed modulo *Phi*, or `(e*d) % Phi == 1` in pseudocode.